# Vec of Rng in struct field, cannot borrow immutable field as mutable

Tags: rust

I wanted to create a `struct`with a field containing a `Vec<ThreadRng>`.

So this works fine, I have a list of generators stored in `Foo.generators`:

```
extern crate rand;

use std::vec::Vec;
use rand::{Rng, ThreadRng};

struct Foo {
    generators: Vec<ThreadRng>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Foo {
        Foo { generators: vec![rand::thread_rng(), rand::thread_rng()]}
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use it, say in a `bar` method:

```
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 {
        self.generators[0].gen::<i32>()
    }
}
```

But that I can't, and I get a `cannot borrow immutable field 'self.generators' as mutable`.

As I understand I cannot use the `gen` method of `ThreadRng` because it requires a mutable reference to the RNG ([`gen<T: Rand>(&mut self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen)) and since the definition of my field `Foo.generators` "`Vec<ThreadRng>`" doesn't specify that the `ThreadRng` should be mutable, I can't do anything with it that requires mutability.

First question: is my understanding of what's happening correct, or am I completely wrong? If so, could someone explain to me what's really happening?

Second question: admitting that my understanding is correct, how am I supposed to allow actions that requires mutability on my `ThreadRng`s?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to borrow `self` mutably:

```
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> i32 {
        self.generators[0].gen::<i32>()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I didn't think it would be that simple... Thank you!